Getting Error "object __array__ method not producing an array" while training a model
I am trying to train a model using the neural network model Sequential. Every thing is going good till the model compilation. As soon as i hit model.fit() for model training i get the error "object array method not producing an array". Please let me know where is the error. I also printed the X_train and y_train samples and their shapes too.
Below is the code for the same.
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np

# Encoding categorical features
label_encoders = {}
for column in consolidated_super.columns:
le = LabelEncoder()
consolidated_super[column] = le.fit_transform(consolidated_super[column])
label_encoders[column] = le

# Split the data into input and output
X = consolidated_super[['DeviceName_df1', 'AlarmName_df1']].values
y = consolidated_super[['DeviceName_df2', 'AlarmName_df2']].values

# One-hot encode the output labels
y_device = to_categorical(consolidated_super['DeviceName_df2'])
y_alarm = to_categorical(consolidated_super['AlarmName_df2'])

# Combine the one-hot encoded outputs
y = np.concatenate([y_device, y_alarm], axis=1)

# Ensure y is numeric and has the correct shape
print(f'X shape: {X.shape}, y shape: {y.shape}')
print(f'X sample: {X[:5]}, y sample: {y[:5]}')
'''
op for above print statements
X shape: (396, 2), y shape: (396, 25)
X sample: [[16 19]
[16 19]
[16 19]
[16 19]
[12 20]], y sample: [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 
0. 0.
1.]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.
0.]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.
0.]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
1.]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.
0.]]
'''

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, 
random_state=42)

# Normalize the input features
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)


# Define the neural network model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax'))  # Use softmax for multi-class 
classification
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=8, validation_split=0.2)

at execution of model.fit() i get the error:-
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[59], line 2
      1 # Train the model
----> 2 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=8, validation_split=0.2)
File C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb
File C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:108, in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    106     dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    107 ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 108 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: object __array__ method not producing an array

sample dataframe is:-
{
    'DeviceName_df1': ['Device A', 'Device B', 'Device C'],
    'AlarmName_df1': ['Alarm1', 'Alarm2', 'Alarm3'],
    'DeviceName_df2': ['Device X', 'Device Y', 'Device Z'],
    'AlarmName_df2': ['Alarm4', 'Alarm5', 'Alarm6']
}

All string values.

what do the fit arguments look like?  What are they?  If not arrays, can you make such?  Shape, dtype?

fit arguments X_train and y_train are array see-:
X_train is like:-
array([[-1.19457482,  0.45940757],
[-0.01897332,  1.5916044 ])
y_train:-
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.],
[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.])

I have checked and got to know that X_train dtype is float64. I think my compiler has some limitation for that so i have explicitly convert that to float32
Explicitly convert data to float32
X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32)
X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32)
y_train = y_train.astype(np.float32)
y_test = y_test.astype(np.float32)
